# Text cursor invisible for custom EditText

Tags: android, cursor

Help needed! I created a custom textbox for input. Keys append fine as I click through the keypad. However for some reason the text cursor is not showing up. What can I possibly missed? Pls advice.

p.s I tried editText.setCursorVisible(true)

I also considered the possibility that the cursor is having the same color as the background..

```
public class ETEditText extends EditText {

public ETEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ETEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ETEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
    return false;
}

}
```

I found that it was actually because I return false on the onCheckIsTextEditor()
but if I make it true I will make the software keyboard show up.. I want to hide it all the time though

any suggestions?

Comment: post your custom textbox code

Comment: create a xml drawable for curser and add it in textCursorDrawable, it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually because false was returned for the onCheckIsTextEditor()
That was done by the original developer for suppressing the keyboard, which is not a good idea since
it suppresses the cursor as well